# Typescript thinks an array is an object

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, ionic4

```js
public handleDesiredCityChange(place: any) {
   this.intPlaces.push(place.formatted_address);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input 
    ngx-google-places-autocomplete 
    [options]='options' 
    #placesRef="ngx-places" 
    (onAddressChange)="handleDesiredCityChange($event)"/>
</div>
```

I declared an array

```
private intPlaces: string[] = [];
```

I can't use `.push` on it with the following:

```
this.intPlaces.push(place.formatted_address);
```

ts is saying i can't use `.push` on type `{}`

Not sure why it doesn't recognize this as an array

Comment: Most likely because `this.intPlaces.push(place.formatted_address);` happens in the wrong context - which is totally missing here. Please post all relevant component code which describes how all of these things are placed in the component.

Comment: Even when I hover over the declaration it's recognized as an object.

Comment: This may be because `place.formatted_address` is not a string.

Comment: @nircraft - `place` is declared as `any` so TS will gladly swallow whatever will come there. It may break something at runtime but not during compilation. So no, that's not it. But from such a small extract of the code, it's really hard to tell what's wrong, there's just not enough information...

Comment: Even when I'm not using it with place.formatted_address...when I hover over the declaration typescript thinks it's {}.  

and it will work if I use the following:

  public handleCityChange(cities: any) {
    this.location = cities.formatted_address;
    console.log('location', this.location);
  }

I can assign the value to a simple string so .formatted_address is a string.

Comment: I'm wondering if this has anything to do with Ionic 4.  I tried declaring an array in a totally different project and it's still not recognized as an array.  Just in the declaration without even trying to use it, when hovering over the array typescript is seeing it as an object.

Comment: This is probably because string will always be single. You should apply any[] = [] to your property. this will work

Comment: Is handleDesiredCityChange in the same class?  Need more context.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Declare array like this,

```
private intPlaces:any = [];
```

If place is array of object then,

```
this.intPlaces.push(place[0].formatted_address);
```